# Reference for a text book on the Toeplitz operators $T:l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb R^2)→l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb R^2)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, toeplitz-operators

We need basic reference on the Toeplitz operators $T:l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb R^2)→l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb R^2)$. Usually text books cover much more subtle case of $T:l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z_+, \mathbb C)→l^{\infty}(\mathbb Z_+, \mathbb C)$.

Comment: In particular we need the following statements:

1. The bounded Toeplitz operators on $l^{\infty}(Z, C^2)$ form a Banach algebra $A$. 

2. Moreover if $S$ and $T$ are bounded operators on $l^{\infty}(Z, C^2)$, $T$ is Toeplitz operator and $S T=I$ then $S$ is also a Toeplitz operator. Analogously, if $T S=I$ then $S$ is a Toeplitz operator.

3. The two Banach algebras $A$ and $\mathbb W$ are isomorphic and isometric. Bijective correspondence is given by $T \mapsto \varphi_{T}$ and $\varphi \mapsto T_{\varphi}$ (Fourier coefficients of $\varphi$ form matrix of $T_{\varphi}$).

Comment: 4. Let $\varphi \in \mathbb W$ then spectrum of $\varphi$ over algebra $\mathbb W$ coincides with spectrum operator $T_{\varphi}$ over algebra $A$.